# Как добавить разделитель в Android OptionsMenu между элементами?

Tags: android, java

Необходимо добавить собственный вертикальный разделитель (линию) между элементами `OptionsMenu`. Версия Android 2.1. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно сделать?

Comment: поиск по хэшкоду сделайте. Был недавно вопрос про кастомизацию меню. Думаю вам пригодится.

Comment: там решение для более старших версий Андроида, а надо именно для 2.1

Comment: вопрос: а зачем?

Comment: На вскидку, установить для actionBar.setCustomLayout(ваш лэйаут);  Или картинки самому устанавливать